# React state is one step behind on useRef()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm specifically tryig to use useRef and this does not seem to be working as my variables are one step behind.  Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**: It is actually not working on the first try (button click: selectSession_Click), after that it works.  Why not on the first call?

```
const seqnumRead = useRef(0);
const seqnumWrite = useRef(0);

// Click a session, bring up detail
const selectSession_Click = (event, sessionId) => {
    const selectedData = data;
    let selSession = selectedData?.filter(s => s.SessionId == sessionId);
    SetSessionSelected(selSession[0]);

    refetch();
    seqnumRead.current = result.payload.read_seqnum;
    seqnumWrite.current = result.payload.write_seqnum;
}

// Fetch seq nums of selected session
const queryKey = 'getData';
const { data: result, isFetching, refetch, } = useQuery([queryKey], fetchSeqNums, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: false,
});
```

seqnumRead & seqnumWrite are a step behind

Comment: if I don't use the useRefs (`seqnumRead` & `seqnumWrite`) and just access directly it works, i'm not sure why                                            `<td>{!seqNumisLoading ? result?.payload.read_seqnum : "...loading"}</td>
                                            <td>{!seqNumisLoading ? result?.payload.write_seqnum : "...loading"}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the result.payload.read_seqnum directly in the render.